# Mongodb Search Query with Populate and regex

Tags: regex, mongodb, mongodb-query

I want regex search on mongodb with NodeJS.

First One is Users and Second one is categories. Here I have saved categories id in Users 
collection. I want a search Query that filter my records.

Users collection

```
{_id:'mongo_id', name:"User First",cat_id:2}
{_id:'mongo_id', name:"User Second",cat_id:2}
{_id:'mongo_id', name:"User Third",cat_id:1}
{_id:'mongo_id', name:"User Fourth",,cat_id:4}
```

Categories
Suppose id is numeric. For demo purpose I have written numeric values.

```
{_id:'1', name:"Salesman",}
{_id:'2', name:"Carpanter"}
{_id:'3', name:"Plumber"}
{_id:'4', name:"Engineer"}
```

I have a text input if I will type Carpanter or Carpan(regex) then I want 2 records, or
When I type User Second or second I want 1 Record

```
var query = {
        'name': {
            $regex: req.body.name,
            $options: 'i'
        }
    };
innerQuery = {
        path: 'category',
        select: 'name'
    }    
Users.find(query)
.populate(innerQuery)
.sort({
    'createdDate': -1
})
```

Comment: Be aware that regex queries are not terribly performant. If you're planning the sort of thing where performance is important and/or you will have lots of documents in the database, you may want to look at implementing this in a different way.

Answer (score 1):

Your user record looks like this:

```
{_id:'mongo_id': name:"User First",cat_id:2}
```

I'll assume the extra `:` is a typo.

Aside from that, you are attempting to query for `title`. There is no path `title` in that record, so you can't query for it.

You're also trying to populate the path `category`, but there is no field with that name in the user records. The only related field I see is `cat_id`.

If you want to, for example, query by `name` and populate the `cat_id`, you can do something like this:

```
var query = {
  'name': {
    $regex: req.body.title,
    $options: 'i'
  }
};

var innerQuery = {
  path: 'cat_id',
  model: 'Category',
  select: 'name'
};
```

This is entirely dependent on whether you named your model `Category`, and also what your schemas actually look like.

(PS, you're also trying to sort by `createdDate`, but I don't see that field in any of your records, either).

Comment: Yes I have modified my question. Is it possible to add regex on both User as well as Category model. Because I want regex on populate also.